# A4j not calling action when rendered by ajax call

Tags: richfaces, ajax4jsf

I'm using RichFaces 4.2.3 and JSF 2.1.

I'm trying to do a ajax request inside a block that is rendered after a hit a button on the screen using the following code.

```
<a4j:commandLink value="Deletar"
     execute="@form"
     render="result"
     action="#{transacaoBean.deletar(10) }"/>
```

When the result is rendered, I get the following error in the javascript console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function (program):1 - (anonymous function) (program):1
runScripts jsf.js.xhtml:335 - doUpdate jsf.js.xhtml:961
response jsf.js.xhtml:2062 - richfaces.queue.response richfaces-queue.js.xhtml:413
jsf.ajax.response richfaces-queue.js.xhtml:50 - onComplete jsf.js.xhtml:1236
AjaxEngine.req.xmlReq.onreadystatechange jsf.js.xhtml:1217
```

If I try to use the same `a4j:commandLink` code but rendering the tag when the page is loaded it works. Do I have to do something different to use a4j when it is rendered as a partial response?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with Mojarra. I had two forms on the screen and there is an issue with more than one form in the screen. Now I'm using a big form around everything and it is working fine.

Comment: Could you give a reference to the bug report regarding this issue?